# I need to get a value from a variable and set is as a string

Tags: javascript

```
var number = +document.getElementById("tall1").value;
document.getElementById("knapp").onclick = doSomething;

function doSomething(){
    var color = document.getElementById("graf1");
    farge.style.height = number + "px";}
```

How do i get the value from var number and set it as height?

Comment: Looks ok as far as `...style.height = number + 'px'` goes. What is `farge` though?

Comment: It seems *number* is a global variable, so what you have should "work", provided the element with ID "tall1" exists when the line of code assigning the value is evaluated/executed. Please see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just re order your code.

```
document.getElementById("knapp").onclick = doSomething;

function doSomething(){
    var number = +document.getElementById("tall1").value;
    var color = document.getElementById("graf1");
    farge.style.height = number + "px";
}
```